# To add nodes dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="post_category" value="1">
parent1(category_names)
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="post_category" value="2">
&nbsp;child1 of parent1
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="post_category" value="3">
&nbsp;child2 of parent1
</li>
```

category names are listed in tree view. The value of checkbox contains id of category

**Question:**
**I need to add category in this list dynamically**

i got new_category name, parent_category_id from user.
I need to add category as same format below the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something simple like:

```
var objList = document.getElementById('mylist');   // need to add ID to OL or UL tag
var objNode = null;

if ( objList != null ) {
    objNode = document.createElement('li');
    if ( objNode != null ) {
        objNode.innerHTML = '~~~CHECKBOX HTML~~~';
        objList.appendChild( objNode );
    } //if
} //if
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have any way (short of using a Regex to parse the text) to determine which element is a parent and which is a child. I'd suggest adding a `parent` and `child` class, and using nesting so that `child`s appear under the `parent`. Otherwise, you'd have to scan each `li` to find the last child after the parent you want, but before the next parent.

Comment: I can fetch the parent by knowing value of check box (ie parent_id)

Comment: I can fetch li using this $('input:checkbox[name=post_category[]]').parent() Help me how to insert a li with checkbox below that parent li

Comment: Do you want a new checkbox after each of the other ones, or just a new `li` with a checkbox?

Comment: just a new li with a checkbox

Comment: Go with Simon Catlin's method